# Laravel Update one form data to different tables using relation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a model user contains below

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
 public function friends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Friends::class);
    }
}
```

and a friends models contains following

```
class friends extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Controller contain following

```
public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());
        $request->user()->save();

        return Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }
```

rules contains related table field `interest`,  i wanted to update that field,

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['email', 'max:255', Rule::unique(User::class)->ignore($this->user()->id)],
            'interest' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:10000']
        ];
    }
```

when i update the form it only update the user model data and not the friends model field `interest`, can someone help please?

Comment: What properties are included in the request? For this context, it could be something like: username : string, password : string, friends : array (of friend ids). Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielHaven i have updated my question, request only include rules.

Comment: interest is a field in the database of friend model, what i want is when i update anything in the form it should update friend model attribute "Interest" as well. i hope this make sense. @DanielHaven

Comment: @Bensih Farooq Sorry, I deleted my last comment because I saw the definition of interest later in the question. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what you've posted thus far, I would say that fill() will take care of the values native to User model. However, if you want to fill in the values of a one-to-many relation, you have to take an extra step.

One-to-many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Inserting data into relations: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

In the controller, you can try something like:

```php
// import App\Models\friends as Friend;


$request->user()->friends()->save(new Friend([
  'interest' => $request->interest
]));
```

The above code adds new friends. To update existing friends, you can do this:

```php
$friends = $request->user()->friends;

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
  $friend->interest = $request->interest;
  $friend->save();
}
```

If the code doesn't work, check if "interest" is added to the $fillables property in your "friends" model. It should go through, but if you use a method like "friends::updateOrCreate", it will not populate if it's not in the $fillables array property.

See mass-assignment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: I think this code will create a new friend. Is your desire to update the "interest" field for the user's existing friends? If so, I'll update the answer. @BenishFarooq

Comment: yes this create a new friend, i want to update the existing friend field interest.

Comment: @BenishFarooq I've updated my answer to include updating existing friends.

Comment: it worked, thank you, last thing is it possible in one save i can update both the tables, so far i am using two save() and i wanted to merge it into one,  i have this foreach ($patients as $patient){
            $patient->explain_interest = $request->interest;
            $patient->save();
        }
        $request->user()->save();

Comment: @BenishFarooq This forum may be relevant: https://laravel.io/forum/06-11-2014-how-to-save-eloquent-model-with-relations-in-one-go